# .before() firing multiple times

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to achieve: reorder the contents of all "row"-divs, so image content always is before text content.

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="image">image content here</div>
    <div class="text">text content here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="text">text content here</div>
    <div class="image">image content here</div>
</div>
```

What it should look like afterwards:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="image">image content here</div>
    <div class="text">text content here</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="image">image content here</div>
    <div class="text">text content here</div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
$('.row').each(function() {
    firstChild = $(this).find(':first-child');
    if(firstChild.hasClass('text')) {
        firstChild.before($(this).find('.image'));
    }
    else {
        console.log("not text");
    }
}
```

The jQuery places the image div in weird orders, after the bit of code I see multiple images placed on the site. Help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just this

```
 $(this).append(firstChild);
```

**instead of**

```
firstChild.before($(this).find('.image'));
```

**Code**

```
$('.row').each(function() {
    var firstChild = $(this).find(':first-child');
    if(firstChild.hasClass('text')) {
       $(this).append(firstChild);
    }
    else {
        console.log("not text");
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcWpz/1/)**